# .Bat file not always executing with Java Code and Eclipse?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, batch-file, testng

.Bat file not always executing with Java Code and Eclipse?

1. For example one test Run would work fine and the .bat file would execute.
2. On the second run no the bat file dosnt execute.
3. Seems to be some inconostencies in relation to the execution of the .bat file.

   ```
   @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true) 
   public void executeBatFile() {
   try{    
       System.out.println("Executing batch file...");
       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/..").toRealPath() + "\\copyPasteImgs.bat");
       //p.waitFor();

   }catch( IOException ex ){
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Try outputting the path that is generated, and also check if the bat file exists at that location.  And if that doesn't yield anything, read the output from the batch file.

Comment: thanks for the comment @Steve Smith, im afraid the location etc is correct, its very strange sometimes it will execute and sometimes it dosnt

Answer (score 0):

Following method seems to be more stable:

```
    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true) 
    public void executeBatFile() {
    try {
        List cmdAndArgs = Arrays.asList("cmd", "/c", "copyPasteImgs.bat");
        File dir = new File(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/..").toRealPath() + "\\");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdAndArgs);
        pb.directory(dir);
        Process p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```